# Rails: database queries too slow for scope that depends on join with another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails 4.1 app (using Postgres as my database) which has a couple of models set up in the following manner:

```
class Components < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :compositions
  scope :abridged, -> { where(abridged: true) }
end

class Compositions < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :component
  scope :abridged, -> { joins(:component).where(components: { abridged: true }) }
  # Or alternatively, { joins(:component).merge(Component.abridged) }
end
```

To summarize:
The `Component` model is referenced by the `Compositions` join model - each composition belongs to one component. The data for these is imported from external CSV files. The components table has a boolean `abridged` column, which defines which components are part of an abridged subset of the data (~85 components out of 360 total). I want easy access to the compositions that are part of this abridged subset (~180,000 compositions out of 400,000), so I have declared a `Composition.abridged` named scope which relies on a join with the components table in order to check the `abridged` condition on the relevant component.

This works correctly, however for certain queries it is very slow. For instance if I am paginating the abridged composition data in my controller like so:
`Composition.abridged.order(:foo_id).page(params[:page])`

I get an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT compositions.* FROM compositions INNER JOIN components
ON components.id = compositions.component_id
WHERE components.abridged = 't'
ORDER BY compositions.foo_id ASC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 185284
```

- which takes around 2000ms on average in my dev VM, compared to ~30ms for an equivalent query on the full data set!

If I remove the `ORDER BY` clause it reduces it to ~80ms, which is not very helpful because then there's no guarantee in which order the records will be returned, but it did suggest that maybe my indexes were at fault. However I tried every possible combination of single/combined index on both tables without any improvement. Doing some `EXPLAIN` queries confirmed that the database simply wasn't utilizing the indexes. After thinking about it I decided this made sense - the database *can't* utilize the indexes efficiently because the filter condition is on another table. If I remove the `WHERE components.abridged = 't'` condition and just do a join without it, then `EXPLAIN` shows that the indexes are used just fine and the query is very fast.

While looking for a way to solve this issue I came across [materialized views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html). Basically this solves my speed issue as it prepopulates what is essentially an additional table with the join query data, so that part only needs to be executed once initially. However this method introduces some major drawbacks in my application - foremost being that it requires (as far as I can tell) a second model, which in turn requires hacky workarounds to avoid duplicating business logic, getting associations right, ensuring that changes occur on the original table instead of being attempted on the materialized view (which can't be changed directly), and that the view is refreshed when something does change (it doesn't do it automatically), etc. If there was a way that I could simply tell the `Compositions.abridged` scope to switch tables without using an extra model then this method would probably be ideal.

So my question is this: **is there a way to query the abridged subset of compositions which allows the simplicity of using a basic scope without incurring a significant speed penalty?**

I haven't mentioned the possibility of adding a boolean column to the `compositions` table. I'm open to this idea but hesitant because of a few reasons:

- It's duplicating data.
- ~400,000 rows need to be initially populated with the correct boolean value (the import process already takes over an hour on my VM), then maintained properly if the abridged components ever change.
- I've heard that the database may not even make use of an index on the `abridged` column anyway, because it accounts for close to half the data set.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you tried: `Composition.where(component_id: Component.abrigded.pluck(:id)).order(foo_id: :asc)`? This should result in a subquery, I think. And it should only order the result not the entire set beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a subquery instead:

```
Composition.where(component_id: Component.abrigded.pluck(:id)).order(foo_id: :asc)
```

so the `order` clause gets involved on the reduced result set already, not the entire result set.

In order to keep the join you should probably get the `abridged = 't'` clause into the join condition:

```
SELECT compositions.* FROM compositions
INNER JOIN components ON components.abridged = 't' AND components.id = compositions.component_id
ORDER BY compositions.foo_id ASC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 185284
```

However, I'm not entirely sure as how to use `ActiveRelation` to do that, despite of using `find_by_sql`.

Comment: After doing some proper testing I determined that the first query is actually slightly slower than my original (by about ~200ms) when used in the same context. The second makes no difference in speed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple query with a join isn't a big problem for Postgres. I think that lack of indexes on your tables is cause of issue.

Have you tried to add index on abridged column of components table? I didn't see this info in your question.

Also check if your compositions table has an index on component_id column.

You can add indexes in new db migration:

```
add_index :compositions, :component_id
add_index :components, :abridged
```

Comment: Yes I had those indexes and others. To quote: "I tried every possible combination of single/combined index on both tables without any improvement."

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this using a [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) in Postgres.